# iOS - String capitalisation when followed by a numeric

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, capitalization

I have a requirement where in first letter of all words in a sentence need to be capitalised. I achieved this through the below code

```
myString = [myString capitalizedString];
```

But there is an issue with this.. if the word starts with a numeric for eg "32abc", after capitalisation it changes to "32Abc". I need it to be "32abc".

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: what if you have @"32Abc", you want it to be @"32abc" or @"32Abc"?

Comment: If it is @"32Abc", it should be shown as @"32Abc" itself.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

```
NSString *input = @"32abc";
/* get first char */
NSString *firstChar = [input substringToIndex:1];

/* remove any diacritic mark */
NSString *folded = [firstChar stringByFoldingWithOptions:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

/* create the new string */
NSString *capitalisedSentence = [[folded uppercaseString] stringByAppendingString:[input substringFromIndex:1]];
```

**Method 2 (Optimized)**

```
NSString *input = @"32abc";
NSString *capitalisedSentence = [input stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)
                                                          withString:[[input substringToIndex:1] capitalizedString]];
```

Comment: I think the OP was speaking about sentences, not a single word "32abc".

Comment: @Sulthan it will do regardless of Sentence or Word.

Comment: input = @"This is a sentence with 32abc."
Expected output (see OP) is "This Is A Sentence With 32abc."

Comment: @Sulthan i have notedown 2 methods, 2nd one is for sentence and 1st is for Word. OP is satisfied with answer. FYI pls have a look at requirement `I have a requirement where in first letter of all words in a sentence need to be capitalised`

Comment: You answer assumes the problematic word is the first one in the sentence and there is only one such a word. The second method completely ignores the word "all" in the requirement. It's not about capitalizing one word, it's about capitalizing all the words (see what `[NSString capitalize]` does).

Comment: @Dipen panchasara: Thank you, but as Sultan said, every first letter of a sentence should be capitalised. Your code provides solution only to the first word.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myString = [myString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString:[[myString substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]];
```